# Have parent and child div. Want my tooltip to drop from child div. It drops when I hover parent div

Tags: html, css

The image is the parent div, the child div is located over a small 
    portion     of the image (parent). The child is the div I want to hover 
    and have the tooltip drop down, but the tooltip drops down when I hover 
    the image (parent). I do not really use HTML and css, so please forgive 
    any newbe blunders. I have found most of the code for the tooltips on 
    various websites. I am soooo far in over my head!!!

I have downloaded snippets from the web. Trying to put
    it together, but just not experienced enough.

```css
/* I do not understand the css, but after several
       weeks of research this is what I have. The Image
       seems to be placed correctly and is the right size.
    */

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: none;
}


/* The tooltip is in fact hidden.*/

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 290px;
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 110%;
}


/* Tooltip becomes visible when hover
         over the big Image. */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* I added this to the sample I downloaded. It
         sizes the Image correctly, and locates it
         where I want it on the Webpage.
    */

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 330px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 5px, #000;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

#container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* This creates the child div. I have located it
         over the area on the Image where I want the
         tooltip to become visible. I put a border 
         around the child so I can see where it is.
    */

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 226px;
  height: 23px;
  border: 1px, #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  background: transparent;
  left: 45px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
/* The below code is where I am really not sure how to use. The tooltip drops down when I hover the Image. I cannot make it so that it only drops when I hover the child. I will send a screenshot if I can figure out how to do so. */
<h2>The Best Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the Image below:</p>
<div class="tooltip"> <img src="MMDVM_Pic.jpg" alt="#">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="tooltiptext"><b><center>More Information About Date and 
        Time</center></b>
      <p style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px">This shows the <font 
        color=”#050778A”;><b>Date and Time </b></font>as reported by <font 
        color=”#ff0000”;><b>pistar.</b></font> There are several <font 
        color=”#E0E614”;>formats</font> supported.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The HTML you're showing has validity problems (unclosed `span`, wrongly closed `div` elements).

Comment: you are applying the :hover effect on the parent, and not the child

Comment: Alon, Notice that the tooltip becomes visible when you hover the child (Black rectangle). It also becomes visible when you hover the parent (small Icon). Stopping it from dropping down from parent hover is the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @MitchSavage Then make the `<div>` dropdown as a parent of the hover, instead of applying it to the parent and expecting the child to get the event, unless you want the answer in **JavaScript**

Answer (score 0):

To start, it's best practice to remove inline styling and add that to your CSS. Then I would recommend using relative units instead of pixel units (20% vs 100px) so that your site can be responsive.

To answer your question, this here is the culprit:

```
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Right now it's activating when you hover over the `.tooltip` (which is the parent). You want it to activate when hovering over the `.tooltiptext`. So that code becomes:

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Chad, when I change to .tooltip .tooltiptext:hover, it does not drop down from parent or child. When I change back to .tooltipHhover .tooltiptext, of course it hovers on parent. Does that indicate that something could be wrong with .tooltiptxt?

Comment: You know what, you probably can't hover over the child since it's hidden. I would replace  `visibility:hidden` with `opacity: 0`, and `visibility: visible` with `opacity: 1`. Transparent elements still are listed in the dom, but hidden elements aren't.

Comment: Chad, when I changed to opacity, no hover on anything., Went back and it still hovers on parent.

Comment: Can you make and post a codepen or jsfiddle with all the code so we can verify?

Comment: Chad, Never have used stackoverflow, codepen or jsfiddle before. I will start now and see if I can make one of those work for us. Thanks, Mitch

Comment: Chad, Made a jsfiddle and posted the html and css there. I think this is the link to jsfiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/jLxpk5ay/ The child <div> is behind the parent <div>.  I could not figure out how to bring it forward. I was able to make href="" and that removed the big Image and you can see the child <div>....  It is "Almost" working!! I really appreciate your help on this! Mitch

Answer (score 0):

You should consider start having the habit of organizing your code with the right identation, so you don't get lost into your own code.

See if that's what you want :

```js
document.getElementById("sibling").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  document.getElementById("child").style.visibility = "visible";
});
document.getElementById("sibling").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  document.getElementById("child").style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.sibling {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.child {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I'm the parent DIV !
  <div class="sibling" id="sibling">I'm the sibling DIV, hover me !</div>
  <div class="child" id="child">Here it goes an example !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Matheus, Tried you example with my Image.  Still drops over the parent. The child div disappeared.  We must use the class dropdown to create the child.

Comment: Then you'll have to adapt it on JavaScript to handle the classes changing over from the parent to the child

Comment: Matheus, You have a good example posted, but it shows the tooltip on boyh the parent and  child...  Thanks...Mitch

Comment: So getting it clearer, you want the child to be created after hovering over the parent and losing the tooltip from the parent div and applying it to the child div, is that right ?

Comment: Matheus, I do not want a tooltip on the parent, only on the child. I am trying to learn how to do this with only one child. Ultimately, I will have 17 child <div>'s on the image, each with a different tooltip. I am doing this now with <map> and <area>. Cannot style my tooltips now. look at https://jsfiddle.net/jLxpk5ay/ to see what I am doing.  The div off to the left with the black border should be a child of the parent (the Image).  I will move the child back over the Image later. Problem is that the dropdown occurs on both the parent and child when either is hovered. Only dropdown on child.

Comment: Edited the code to figure out the "behind-the-scenes" over parenting and turns out that creating the event over the sibling solved the issue for me using the JavaScript's `addEventListener`, see if that's what you're wondering to happen now

Comment: Matheus, I am closing in on a solution.  I will try to post a jsfiddle later today.  Hopefully with a working solution.  I am constructing a hobby website for my friends to use. It is coming together.